# Trigger click on accordion link by clicking the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some issue with a trigger. Actually I want my accordions to collapse, not only by clicking on the link but also clicking on the whole header panel. This is my header's code

```
<div class="accordion-head" role="tab">
    <div class="head-title">
        <div>
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordion-body">Commande n°240A
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="date-cmd">
            02/04/2017
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="head-arrow">
       <i style="display: none;" class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript code

```
$('.accordion-head').on("click", function (){
    $(this).find('a').trigger("click");
});
```

But it's not working. I'm using "$(this)" because I want to access the link in unique way (there are other accordions)
Thanks for help.

I added a fiddle with all my code https://jsfiddle.net/ws7rb68z/4/

Comment: Can you attach example of the accordion you made of? because it looks like you miss the content of the accordion.

Comment: Adding a snippet and reproducing the issue will be helpful for providing the solution

Comment: Ok i will add a JsFiddle

Comment: snippet here https://jsfiddle.net/ws7rb68z/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because of the anchor element being inside of the accordion header. So when triggering the click on the anchor, it "clicks" on the header, which then triggers the click on anchor again, causing an infinite loop of clicks. To prevent this, when clicking on the header, check that the click wasn't inside of the anchor. Something like the following:

```
$('.accordion-head').on("click", function (event){
    if(!$(event.target).closest('a').length) {
        $(this).find('a').trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Example in the JSFiddle you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/ws7rb68z/5/

Comment: Thanks. Your solution actually stops the loop I had..but the accordion still not collapsing

Comment: @DavidWesson Could you provide the accordion's code? Including the HTML? As asked by the comments on the question

Comment: @DavidWesson I updated my answer to use the JSFiddle you provided, and it works.